# MYSQL - Query cross columns in single table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table with the columns as follows

[image]

I wanted to remove the rows where the MSGTO and MSGFROM  cross references. The table is use for messaging. The goal is to show only the rows which has no response yet.

My current SQL seem way off.

```
SELECT *
from inbox
where MSGTO > MSGFROM and
      exists (select 1 from inbox t2 where t2.MSGFROM = MSGTO and t2.MSGTO = MSGFROM)
```

Desired output should only be
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LEFT JOIN`

```
select *
from your_table yt
  left join your_table yt2
    on yt1.MSGFROM = yt2.MSGTO
   and yt1.MSGTO = yt2.MSGFROM
where yt2.MID is null
```

When `yt2.MID is null` means there is no answer for that message